# Find the distributional derivative $u''$ of $u(x)=\vert x^2-1\vert$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, distribution-theory

I am new to distributions and I want to make sure I understand how to do computations with them. So I was trying out this problem:
**Problem:** Let $u(x)=\vert x^2-1\vert$ be a function on $\mathbb R$. Find its distributional derivative $u''.$

**My Attempt:** Let $\psi\in\mathcal C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$. By the definition of the derivative of a distributio and using integration by parts we have,
\begin{align*}
u'(\psi)&=-u(\psi')=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\vert x^2-1\vert\psi'(x)\,dx\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^{-1}(x^2-1)\psi'(x)\,dx+\int_{-1}^1(x^2-1)\psi'(x)\,dx-\int_1^\infty(x^2-1)\psi'(x)\,dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}2x\psi(x)\,dx-\int_{-1}^12x\psi(x)\,dx+\int_1^\infty 2x\psi(x)\,dx.
\end{align*}
Then using integration by parts again we get,
\begin{align*}
u''(\psi)&=-\int_{-\infty}^{-1}2x\psi'(x)\,dx+\int_{-1}^12x\psi'(x)\,dx-\int_1^\infty 2x\psi'(x)\,dx\\
&=2\left[2\psi(1)+2\psi(-1)+\int_{\vert x\vert>1}\psi(x)\,dx-\int_{-1}^1\psi(x)\,dx\right]\\
&=2\left[2\delta_1(\psi)+2\delta_{-1}(\psi)+\int_{\vert x\vert>1}\psi(x)\,dx-\int_{-1}^1\psi(x)\,dx\right].
\end{align*}
We conclude that
$$u''=4\delta_1+4\delta_{-1}+2\cdot\mathbf1_{\{\vert x\vert>1\}}-2\cdot\mathbf1_{[-1,1]}.$$

---

Do you agree with my computation above?
Any feedback is much appreciated. Thank you for your time.